# LLDP in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-8.1, lldp

How do i make LLDP in Windows 2012 R2/Windows 8.1 give me some useful info, like, let's say ComputerName.

From my Cisco Catalyst switch, LLDP neighbor is a Windows 8.1 box:

```
SWITCH# show lldp neigh detail

Chassis id: 0026.2dfb.e215
Port id: 0026.2dfb.e215
Port Description - not advertised
System Name - not advertised
System Description - not advertised

Time remaining: 3451 seconds
System Capabilities - not advertised
Enabled Capabilities - not advertised
Management Addresses - not advertised
Auto Negotiation - supported, enabled
Physical media capabilities:
1000baseT(FD)
Media Attachment Unit type - not advertised
Vlan ID: - not advertised

MED Information:

MED Codes:
      (NP) Network Policy, (LI) Location Identification
      (PS) Power Source Entity, (PD) Power Device
      (IN) Inventory

Inventory information - not advertised
Capabilities:
Device type: Endpoint Class I
Network Policies - not advertised
Power requirements - not advertised
Location - not advertised
```

---

This is literally not saying anything in 25 lines.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I simply cannot understand why MS would include LLDP in their network stack and then the only useful information is the MAC address which I get from the switch anyways.

Comment: Dear Microsoft Enterprise Networking Team, if you drop by, please open our eyes here.

Comment: I wrote my own implementation of an LLDP broadcast service as I don't think there is any documentation on how to configure the MS kernel driver. I'll post a link to github as soon as it's somewhat production ready.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, it simply does not work on windows 2012 r2.

Here are the steps I have done to try to install the protocol:

On windows 2012 you should install DCB:

On powershell, launched as administrator:

> Install-WindowsFeature Data-Center-Bridging

Then install lldp protocol on the interface, sadly a cisco nexus device does not see anything coming from the server.

Answer (score 2):

LLDP support in 8.1 is most likely primarily for Skype for Business support, specifically for location information for E911 applications. The Skype for Business client pulls the neighbor id from the switch it is connected to through the LLDP driver, and send it to the Lync/Skype servers to get a physical location.

Comment: Skype thinks it's going to get a physical location out of an adjacent switch's ID?  I don't know what you put in *your* LLDP info, but I certainly don't put lat/long in there...

Comment: @womble: LLDP-MED does have a lat/long field though, doesn't it?